# What is meant by auxiliary connection in openflow?

Tags: sdn

I am using onos controller and trying sample topos with mininet. while reading openflow 1.3.5 doc, I couldnt understand whats is meant by auxiliary connection and how to configure it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of an out-of-band connection, the openflow channel between the switch and the controller is established through a dedicated port on the switch. This port is used only for openflow messages.

You can see the management port of Brocade ICX 7450 (port located top-left).
[Brocade ICX 7450 - Openflow Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1qh1.png)

Additional ports can be defined for Openflow channel due to various reasons *(redundancy, load balancing)*. Openflow connection established through additional ports is called auxiliary connection. By defining auxiliary connection, we have multiple connections (Openflow channel) between the switch and the controller.

In order to make OpenFlow communication via the auxiliary port, the main channel connection must first be established. If the main channel connection is off, the auxiliary connections are also cannot used. In case of functionally, there is no difference between main channel connection and auxiliary connection.

The switcher must assign an auxiliaryId value for the auxiliary connection and use the same DatapathId value as the main channel.

Comment: "the main channel connection must first be established". What if the management port has failed? Then we can't have auxiliary connection too?
I'm new in SDN and may missed something.